# Sending images with AndroidAnnotations RestService

Tags: android, spring, android-annotations

What is the best way to send a file using the RestService? I have an image that I have to send to the server.

The API expects the following POST data:

```
image -> image I want to send
description -> text
title -> text
```

Can I just send an object with the needed values to achieve this or do I have to do it another way?

```
class NewImage {
    private Bitmap image;
    private String description;
    private String title;
}
```

Comment: Have you seen these two links : https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/1201 and https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/660 ?

Comment: No I haven't. So I have to send a MultiValueMap with a FileSystemResource for the image and a String for the description and title?

Comment: Thats what mrljdx suggest in the first thread.

Comment: Those posts are not entirely correct. I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a multipart POST request:

Client:

```
@Rest(rootUrl = "your_url", converters = FormHttpMessageConverter.class)
public interface UploadClient extends RestClientHeaders {
    @Post("/Image/{id}")
    @RequiresHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE)  
    String uploadImage(int id, MultiValueMap<String, Object> data);     
}
```

Usage:

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> data = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

FileSystemResource image = new FileSystemResource("path_to_image");
String description = "description";
String title = "title";

data.put("image", image);
data.put("description", description);
data.put("title", title);

client.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE);

client.uploadImage(1, data);
```

I know this has some boilerplate, but it will be [improved](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/pull/1448) in the near future.

Reflect for the question in the comment:

You can create a class:

```
class ObjectSupportingFormHttpMessageConverter extends FormHttpMessageConverter {
    public ObjectSupportingFormHttpMessageConverter() {
        addPartConverter(new ObjectToStringHttpMessageConverter(new DefaultConversionService()));
    }
}
```

Then use it as a converter. This will convert your objects to text/plain parts. However, maybe it is better to serialize this complex structure into JSON instead of sending it in the multipart post.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But now I also want to send a float, double, boolean and a date with the request. But I get the error: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [java.lang.Long] What MessageConverter do I have to use for this? Or should I convert them all to String?